# Add coded control to UIMap (Coded UI Test)

Tags: unit-testing, mstest, coded-ui-tests, handwriting

I would like to add a handwritten coded control to my UIMap.cs (not UIMap.Designer.cs).

For example, when I record: `writing in a texBox`, I get the following code in UIMap.Designer.cs:

```
public class Recorded_Writing_In_forRecordParams
{
    public string UIForRecordEditText = "forRecord";
}

public class UIMainWindowWindow : WpfWindow
{
    public UIMainWindowWindow()
    {
        this.SearchProperties[WpfWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = "MainWindow";
        this.SearchProperties.Add(new PropertyExpression(WpfWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName, "HwndWrapper", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains));
        this.WindowTitles.Add("MainWindow");
    }

    public WpfEdit UIForRecordEdit
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mUIForRecordEdit == null))
            {
                this.mUIForRecordEdit = new WpfEdit(this);
                this.mUIForRecordEdit.SearchProperties[WpfEdit.PropertyNames.AutomationId] = "forRecord";
                this.mUIForRecordEdit.WindowTitles.Add("MainWindow");
            }

            return this.mUIForRecordEdit;
        }
    }

    private WpfEdit mUIForRecordEdit;
}
```

I want use this control in my `CodedUITest`. Is there a way to search the `TextBox` in the `UIMap.cs` by own coded or to search it in my `TestMethod`? Which is the best way?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Why would you search the UIMap for a textbox in your code? Or are you wanting to search your application for a textbox with a given value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answer, but I solved my problem on my own with the following way:

**UIMap.cs**

```
public partial class TestLittleAppUIMap
{
    private MyWindow mMyWindow;
    public MyWindow MMyWindow
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.mMyWindow == null)
            {
                this.mMyWindow = new MyWindow();
            }
            return this.mMyWindow;
        }
    }
}

public class MyWindow : WpfWindow
{ 
    private WpfEdit mWpfEdit;

    public MyWindow()
    {
        this.SearchProperties[WpfWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = "MainWindow";
        this.SearchProperties.Add(new PropertyExpression(WpfWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName, "HwndWrapper", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains));
        this.WindowTitles.Add("MainWindow");
    }

    public WpfEdit MWpfEdit
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mWpfEdit == null))
            {
                this.mWpfEdit = new WpfEdit(this);
                #region Search Criteria
                this.mWpfEdit.SearchProperties[WpfEdit.PropertyNames.AutomationId] = "forOwn";
                this.mWpfEdit.WindowTitles.Add("MainWindow");
                #endregion
            }
            return this.mWpfEdit;
        }
    }
```

**CodedUI Test**

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestLittleAppOwnMap()
{
    this.UIMap.MMyWindow.MWpfEdit.DrawHighlight();
    Playback.Wait(2500);
}
```

It is almost a copy of the designer class.

For searching directly in the `TestMethod` you can go like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestLittleAppOwn()
{
    WpfWindow w = new WpfWindow();
    w.SearchProperties[WpfWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = "MainWindow";
    w.SearchProperties.Add(new PropertyExpression(WpfWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName, "HwndWrapper", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains));
    w.DrawHighlight();

    WpfEdit e = new WpfEdit(w);
    e.SearchProperties[WpfEdit.PropertyNames.AutomationId] = "forOwn";
    e.SetProperty("Text","myText");
    e.DrawHighlight();
    Playback.Wait(2500);
}
```

Where `Playback.Wait` just wait a short time for showing the Highlight.